# Android app publishing language question

Tags: android, publish

1. Can I upload the same application in different languages to the market? I have a language-specific app that should be hungarian for hungarian users and finnish for finnish users etc. The icon of the app would be slightly different for each languages, but everything else would be the same. In this case i would have e.g. 5 lite and 5 pro versions of the same app in the market but in different languages. Is this permitted?
2. The description can be translated with google translator but that's not very good considering we are talking about business. Shall i use english for all the languages i do not speak or use the google translator? Or e.g. if i select Finland for the country i want to distribute my app in, shall i translate the description with google translator? Or will google translator automatically translate it when i select Finland for the location?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. You can do everything you asked for. Detailed information about that can be found in the [application resources section](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html). I am not sure if the application icon will be different in the market overview but as soon as the application is installed, the localized icon should be visible. It should be enough to publish your app twice, once as free, once as a pro version
2. You should provide English as a default language and translate for every supported language. If your app is a business application you should think about hiring a native speaker for your translation. If you make your strings.xml in a good way (understandable names for the string) the translation should be easy and not very expensive.